# Supporting Ridge Beam Post with LVL?

Tags: structural, beam

I want to open this span (about 12') and planning to purchase 2 x 10" LVL's which will sit beneath the double top plate that is already there (so our beam will be 12.5" tall x 3.5" thick). There is only roof above (no floor) and it pitches away from the camera in the kitchen. The garage is below and a beam runs parallel to this wall.

I'm wondering about the ridge beam and specifically the double 2x4 post in the wall directly below. I would like to remove that and have my new beam sit on a post about 12" to the right of where that one is. Wanted to get others thoughts on this approach and see if there were concerns about not having a post directly below the ridge beam.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a structural engineer to sign off your designs before you start cutting structural timbers.  However:

There is no problem in principle in running a suitably sized blue beam to the right of the current post.  What you *may* need, is a post running from the blue beam directly up to the ridge. This would leave you the completely open space at floor level, but would be visible in the open space above the beam.

Does the existing post run all the way to the roof?  If not, you won't need one in the new scheme.  If it does, you will.

Comment: I think the post you suggest is exactly what's being asked about. I agree otherwise.

Comment: @isherwood My point is that the ridge post can be (effectively) dog-legged.  Vertically down from the ridge to the beam, and then offset at the beam, and vertically down from the end of the beam (this will obviously impose more load on the beam - but that is just a matter of sizing correctly).

Comment: Re-reading, it's not entirely clear whether that was the OP's intent. I agree that a post under the ridge (assuming one exists now) should be retained.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. In that attic space there is a post directly underneath that sits on this wall (I would not be touching this). It sits on the double 2x4 top plate which would be above my new beam.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making the blue beam extend right-ward 2 or 3 studs to more evenly distribute the load. Doing so may even allow for other size options on your proposed LVL. If it were me, I'd use steel I-beams for the horizontal and the vertical. (But I know that is not a cheap option).

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend a post from the large ridge beam directly through the basement to the existing footing.

A beam that large with an existing post in the attic (and directly under it on the main floor,) I’m sure has a post extending through the basement to a footing.

Moving the post is not advisable.

Btw, you imply that there is a post in the attic that sits on the double top plate of the main floor. I’m surprised, because that puts a splice (hinge) in the post. Then, there’s another splice (hinge) at the floor level of the main level. If you live in a high wind area or a seismically active area, you should add connectors at each splice and insure the post won’t bend like a hinge by installing some plywood connecting the post into the rest of the house.

Comment: There is no post or footing below this point in the basement, but it does sit close to a floor joist.

Comment: @What-About-Bob Is the ridge beam fake or over sized for aesthetics?

Comment: I don't think it's fake in anyway, but I guess it could have been oversized. It was built in 1980.

Comment: The basement in general is supported by a steel beam and steel posts. I was expecting this point to be supported by that, but it is not. In fact, this wall is only partially supported by a floor joist.

Comment: @What-About-Bob Hmmm...very strange. It needs some support and needs to transfer the roof load to the ground. Anything near that post other than one joists? Is there a beam in the attic that supports the post?